# How does Keras back propagate custom loss function?

Tags: machine-learning, keras

I've studied plenty of examples of custom loss functions for Keras. All of them can be summaraized as "just write it". Namely, one need to write function taking parameters (y_true, y_pred). But normally CNN needs a derivative of a loss function for back propagation. For instance, if you implement custom loss in Caffe, you have to write 2 function: the loss you need itself, and it's derivative for backward propagation. But in Keras it seems you have no need in the 2nd one. How does this magic works?

Answer (score 6):

The magic is called automatic differentiation (AD). Keras is built on top of symbolic computational frameworks, namely Theano, TensorFlow, and/or CNTK. These frameworks allow you to define the loss as a symbolic expression, which can be easily be differentiated at runtime, as the whole representation is symbolic.

In contrast, Caffe is built in C++ and does not use any symbolic representation framework, and as you mention, it needs to specify the loss function and its gradient analytically in code.