# Writing custom loss in tensorflow that does not use Y_pred and Y_actual

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, loss-function

My loss function for a DNN classification task is eigenvalue-based which does not need the inputs Y_prediction and Y_actual. Is it possible to write specialized custom loss functions like that using Tensorflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course:

```
def customLoss(y_true, y_pred, alpha):
               loss = ....alpha
                return loss
model.compile(loss=customLoss(alpha), optimizer='sgd')
```

Comment: A great answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48104544/how-does-keras-back-propagate-custom-loss-function